# Can I use `peer channel fetch config` with only orderer nodes, no peer nodes?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I've brought up an etcdraft based orderer cluster with 3 nodes and no peer nodes are deployed for now. And now I want to modify the orderer cluster like removing or adding members. Instructions I've found require firstly fetching the current config with the 'peer channel fetch config' command.

My question is how I can do to fetch the current system channel config with 'peer channel fetch config' command before/without any peer up and running, or is there any other way to achieve this.

- fabric version: 1.4.4

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke it against an orderer since you also need to do this for the system channel, and peers don't have the system channel in them.

Use something like:

```
peer channel fetch config mychannel.block -c mychannel --orderer orderer.example.com:7050 --cafile ca.crt
```